# How to get a date (month, day, year) from the number of seconds passed since January 1, 1970 in Lua?

Tags: lua

I have this so far:

```
function Date(T)
    if not T then return "never" end
    local Z = math.floor(T/86400)+719468
    local ERA = math.floor(Z/146097)
    local DOE = math.floor(Z-ERA*146097)
    local YOE = math.floor((DOE-DOE/1460+DOE/36524-DOE/146096)/365)
    local DOY = DOE-math.floor((365*YOE+YOE/4-YOE/100))
    local MP = math.floor((5*DOY+2)/153)
    local M = math.floor(MP+(MP<10 and 3 or -9))
    return ({"January", "Febuary", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"})[M].." "..math.ceil(DOY-(153*MP+2)/5+1)..", "..math.floor(YOE+ERA*400)+(M<=2 and 1 or 0)
end
```

As far as I can tell it works, but it looks messy and I need a cleaner implementation. What is the standard way to do what I described in the title?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```lua
print(os.date("%H:%M:%S"))

for k,v in pairs(os.date("*t")) do
    print(k,v)
end
```

os.date is a built-in function in Lua, first argument is the format, it can be values like `%H:%M:%S` or `*t`, first will return a string, second will return a table with each date type (second, month, day, etc). You can specify second argument, otherwise it equals to `os.time()`.

Documentation: https://www.lua.org/manual/5.4/manual.html#pdf-os.date

Comment: What if the tick is arbitrary, not now?

Comment: @user15074445 Second argument is the time, if not specified it equals to `os.time()` (current time). Example: `os.date("%c", 0)`

Comment: @Spar That's not necessarily how it works on every platform; `os.time()` returns a number representing the current time, but it's not defined how that number should be interpreted.

Comment: @DarkWiiPlayer I'm doing it on Roblox

Answer (score 0):

```lua
os.date("%c", os.time{year=1970, month=1, day=1, hour=math.floor(tonumber(os.date"%z")/60), sec=0})
```

This should work reliably in all time zones that are only full hours offset from UTC. It also assumes Lua was compiled with C99 features.